# Difference between scan(...) and subscribe(...) in rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I've googled the issue expecting that there's been a gazillion curious people before me asking it too. For some reason, most hits are on scan vs reduce (which I clearly understand). So there's a risk that I totally misunderstood the docs.

According to the docs, [scan(...)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-scan) will snatch an emitted value, do stuff to it and then, optionally pass it on to the next person in line. Meanwhile, [subscribe(...)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-subscribe), although accepting parameters for handling of errors and completion, does the very same thing.

I understand the "difference" between them but it appears to me as rather insignificant from the aspect of development tooling. Is it as simple as that the former only a convenience method for cases where the latter would require mundane coding? Or is there a fundamental difference between them (as in: something I can do with scanning that I can't achieve subscribing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan() and Subscribe() are quite different concepts in RxJS.

**Scan** is an operator for combining values coming through the stream with previous values that came through the stream, and then outputting some combination of them (I think scan and reduce are the only operators that does this). Subscribe only works on the current value that comes through the stream.

**Subscribe** is a special method and one of the most important concepts in RxJS. Subscribe comes at the end of the Observable stream, this is where you can use the resulting value for something. From all other operators you return something that can be passed down the chain, but you do not return from subscribe.

If you are working with cold Observables (which you very often are), you need to subscribe to it in order for the code to run at all. If you have no subscriptions on a cold observable, then none of the code in your Observable stream will run.

**The syntax for using them is also different.** Scan is an operator that you chain inside the pipe() method like map, reduce, filter, tap, mergeMap, flatMap, etc. It looks like:

```
myObservable$.pipe(map(...), scan(...), flatMap(...));
```

Subscribe is a method like pipe that you dot chain, like:

```
myObservable$.pipe(...).subscribe(...);
```